# Contents of Angular Sidenav material container don't render

Tags: angular, dom, angular-material, stackblitz, mat-sidenav

I am trying to use the angular material sidenav in my project but when I add it to the project it causes the entire page to be blank (white) and when I inspect the DOM nothing inside of mat-sidenav-container is rendered. I'm sure whatever I'm doing or not doing is very simple. I have used other angular materials in my project successfully already (namely the toolbar).

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bcujpz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import `BrowserAnimationsModule` in your app module and it will render as expected.

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
```

Comment: I knew it would be something simple! Amazing that this isn't mentioned in the various tutorials/videos I watched trying to figure out where I went wrong. Thank you!